# Convert numpy array to binary array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

Say I have a 3D numpy array `(100*100*4)`. I would like to convert non-255 vector ([255,255,255,255]) to [0,0,0,255]

```py
# genearte a numpy array
np.random.seed(seed=777)
s = np.random.randint(low=0, high = 255, size=(100, 100, 4))
print(s)
```

Currently this is my approach but seems very slow, is there a better way? Any help is appreciated.

```py
def foo(x): 
    y= np.full_like(x, 255)
    for iy, ix in np.ndindex(x.shape[0:2]):
        if not np.all(x[iy, ix] == 255):
            y[iy, ix] = np.array([0, 0, 0, 255]) 
    return
```

Comment: Also foo seems to change your entire array to [0,0,0,255]. Is that your intended output? Or did you only want to change arrays to [0,0,0,255] if the array elements are [255,255,255,255]. And if it is your intended output could you explain why you think it is slow?

Comment: if the vector is not [255,255,255,255] then change the whole vector to [0,0,0,255].

Comment: basically, i just want to keep those  [255,255,255,255] vector and turn the rest to [0,0,0,255], i am wondering is there a simpler to do that in numpy

Comment: From the fine docs: _"high : int or array-like of ints, optional \n 
    If provided, **one above the largest (signed) integer** to be drawn"_ (emphasis mine).

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```py
# get boolean array where entries are equal to [255, 255, 255, 255]
b = (s[:, :] == np.array([255, 255, 255, 255])).all(axis=2)

# set values where b is False to [0, 0, 0, 255]
s[~b] = np.array([0, 0, 0, 255])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and [boolean array indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```py
import numpy as np

s = np.array(
    [
        [
            [255, 255, 255, 255],
            [255, 255, 255, 255],
            [255, 200, 255, 255],
            [200, 255, 255, 255],
            [200, 255, 255, 255],
        ],
        [
            [255, 255, 255, 255],
            [200, 255, 255, 255],
            [255, 200, 255, 255],
            [255, 255, 200, 255],
            [255, 255, 200, 255],
        ]
    ]
)

mask = (s != 255).any(axis=-1)
s[mask] = [0, 0, 0, 255]
```

```py
>>> s
array([[[255, 255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255, 255],
        [  0,   0,   0, 255],
        [  0,   0,   0, 255],
        [  0,   0,   0, 255]],

       [[255, 255, 255, 255],
        [  0,   0,   0, 255],
        [  0,   0,   0, 255],
        [  0,   0,   0, 255],
        [  0,   0,   0, 255]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a smaller array with a smaller variation of values, so that you can check my results easily.

Here the first idea is to reshape the data array so that each of the rows is one of the 4-uple that you want to test against `(255, 255, 255, 255)`,
the second one is to use the `.all(axis=1)` method ([thank you mozway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75662903/2749397)) to have a 1D Boolean array that can be used to index the view.

```
In [189]: import numpy as np
     ...: np.random.seed(2023-3-7)
     ...: 
     ...: # CONSTANTS
     ...: MILLE_VENTI = np.array((255, 255, 255, 255), dtype=int)
     ...: REPLACEMENT = np.array((  0,   0,   0, 255), dtype=int)
     ...: H, W, D = 6, 6, 4
     ...: 
     ...: # your array (with a higher chance of a MILLE_VENTI) and a view of it
     ...: s = np.random.randint(low=254, high = 256, size=(H, W, D))
     ...: v = s.reshape(-1,4) # v is a VIEW of s
     ...: 
     ...: # compute a 1D boolean array and check if we have a "hit"
     ...: is_milleventi = (v==MILLE_VENTI).all(axis=1)
     ...: print(*((n, arr) for n, arr in enumerate(v) if is_milleventi[n]))
     :::: 
     ...: # assign the replacement values to the rows that DO NOT satisfy condition
     ...: v[~is_milleventi] = replacement
     ...: 
     ...: # check that the original array has been correctly mofified
     ...: print(s)
(29, array([255, 255, 255, 255]))
[[[  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]]

 [[  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]]

 [[  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]]

 [[  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]]

 [[  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [255 255 255 255]]

 [[  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]]]

In [190]:
```

Answer (score 1):

Listing [[NumPy]: Routines](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.html#routines).

This is more like an exercise: I wanted to do a comparison between the existing variants (from question and answers).

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import timeit

import numpy as np


def _user16971617(arr):
    ret = np.full_like(arr, 255)
    for iy, ix in np.ndindex(arr.shape[0:2]):
        if not np.all(arr[iy, ix] == 255):
            ret[iy, ix] = np.array([0, 0, 0, 255]) 
    return ret


def _matt_pitkin(arr):
    ret = np.copy(arr)
    b = (ret[:, :] == np.array([255, 255, 255, 255])).all(axis=2)
    ret[~b] = np.array([0, 0, 0, 255])
    return ret



def _paime(arr):
    ret = np.copy(arr)
    mask = (ret != 255).any(axis=-1)
    ret[mask] = [0, 0, 0, 255]
    return ret


def _roman_perekhrest(arr):
    ret = np.copy(arr)
    return np.where((ret != [255, 255, 255, 255]).any(-1)[:, :, None], [0, 0, 0, 255], ret)


FUNCS = (
    _user16971617,
    _matt_pitkin,
    _paime,
    _roman_perekhrest,
)


def test_acc():
    print("\nACCURACY")
    arr = np.array((
        (
            (255, 255, 255, 255),
            (255, 0, 0, 0),
            (255, 255, 0, 0),
            (255, 0, 255, 0),
            (255, 0, 0, 255),
            (0, 255, 255, 0),
            (0, 255, 0, 255),
            (0, 0, 255, 255),
        ), (
            (1, 2, 3, 4),
            (0, 255, 0, 0),
            (1, 2, 255, 0),
            (1, 0, 2, 255),
            (255, 255, 255, 0),
            (255, 255, 0, 255),
            (255, 0, 255, 255),
            (0, 255, 255, 255),
        )), dtype=np.uint8)
    exp = np.array((((0, 0, 0, 255),) * arr.shape[1],) * arr.shape[0], dtype=np.uint8)
    exp[0][0] = (255, 255, 255, 255)
    print("Expected result:\n{:}\n".format(exp))
    for func in FUNCS:
        print("Probing function: {:s}".format(func.__name__))
        ret = func(arr)
        if not np.array_equal(exp, ret):
            print("DIFFERENT result:\n{:}".format(ret))


def test_perf():
    print("\nPERFORMANCE")
    arr = np.random.randint(low=0, high = 255, size=(100, 100, 4), dtype=np.uint8)
    res = []
    for func in FUNCS:
        res.append((func.__name__, timeit.timeit(lambda: func(arr), number=200)))
    print("Function results:")
    for n, t in sorted(res, key=lambda arg: arg[1], reverse=True):
        print("Function {:s}: {:.3f} seconds".format(n, t))


def main(*argv):
    test_acc()
    test_perf()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> (py_pc064_03.10_test1_pycoral) [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackExchange/StackOverflow/q075659888]> python ./code00.py 
> Python 3.10.7 (main, Sep  7 2022, 15:22:19) [GCC 9.4.0] 064bit on linux
>
>
> ACCURACY
> Expected result:
> [[[255 255 255 255]
>   [  0   0   0 255]
>   [  0   0   0 255]
>   [  0   0   0 255]
>   [  0   0   0 255]
>   [  0   0   0 255]
>   [  0   0   0 255]
>   [  0   0   0 255]]
>
>  [[  0   0   0 255]
>   [  0   0   0 255]
>   [  0   0   0 255]
>   [  0   0   0 255]
>   [  0   0   0 255]
>   [  0   0   0 255]
>   [  0   0   0 255]
>   [  0   0   0 255]]]
>
> Probing function: _user16971617
> Probing function: _matt_pitkin
> Probing function: _paime
> Probing function: _roman_perekhrest
>
> PERFORMANCE
> Function results:
> Function _user16971617: 17.288 seconds
> Function _matt_pitkin: 0.123 seconds
> Function _roman_perekhrest: 0.109 seconds
> Function _paime: 0.081 seconds
>
> Done.
> ```

**Notes**:

- Original approach is hundreds of times slower than the other 3 (which make use of *NumPy*'s vectorized routines) which are pretty close to each other (although @paime's seems to be the fastest)
- In order to keep variants consistent (with the 1<sup>st</sup> one), the faster ones also copy the array. That translates to a (small) penalty, meaning that they will perform slightly better if modifying the array in place

Answer (score 0):

You can apply [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy.where) to apply values depending on condition:

```
s = np.where((s != [255,255,255,255]).any(-1)[:,:,None], [0, 0, 0, 255], s)
```

Comment: I know what *np.place* does, but if you test it on an array (take the one from @paime's answer for example) it doesn't yield the expected result.