# 2D array, check which rows are equal to a 1D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array, `N` rows and `2` columns,

```
arr = np.arange(200, dtype=int).reshape(-1,2)
```

and you know that `arr[50]` is `[100, 101]`, but I don't know that, so I write

```
guess = np.array((100, 101), dtype=int)
arr == guess
```

expecting a 1D boolean array with `N` elements, but instead I get a 2D boolean array, `N` rows and `2` columns.

Is it possible to have an 1D boolean array, that singles out the rows of my array that are equal, member by member, to the guess array? no loops, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate with [`all`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html#numpy.all) to ensure having True for both (all) columns:

```
(arr == guess).all(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, # 50 is here
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False])
```

Comment: Before posting I aggregated _too much_ with `.all()`. Thank you.